# Solve these error when use post method then gives an error in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, post

Please solve my problem when i use post method in node js connect to  mongodb then this error will appear

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected number in JSON at position 31
at JSON.parse (\<anonymous\>)
at parse (C:\\Users\\dat\\Desktop\\node js\\node_modules\\body-parser\\lib\\types\\json.js:89:19)
at C:\\Users\\dat\\Desktop\\node js\\node_modules\\body-parser\\lib\\read.js:128:18
at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:204:9)
at invokeCallback (C:\\Users\\dat\\Desktop\\node js\\node_modules\\raw-body\\index.js:231:16)
at done (C:\\Users\\dat\\Desktop\\node js\\node_modules\\raw-body\\index.js:220:7)
at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\\Users\\dat\\Desktop\\node js\\node_modules\\raw-body\\index.js:280:7)
at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:513:28)
at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
```

My code is

```
const express=require('express');
require('./config');
const changeproduct=require('./productschema');
const app=express();
app.use(express.json())
app.post('/open',async (req,res)=\>{
let data=new changeproduct(req.body);
let result= await data.save();
console.log(req.body);
res.send('done');
})`

app.listen('600');`your text`
```

please solve my problem and send me the soolution.

i need the best solution for these problem`

Comment: Can you share the request you send to this endpoint?

Comment: What does `console.log(req.body);` show? `(req,res)=\>` should be `(req,res)=>`

Answer (score 0):

There may be error in this module:

```
const changeproduct = require('./productschema');
```

Your Schema may not be properly formatted.